# rsync NFS charset issue

Tags: nfs

I am trying to sync data to a NFS share provided by a Dell Compellent FS8600 NFS appliance.

I am trying to sync files with characters that are non-ascii, and I get this error:

> rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat
>   "/nfs/web/c7392/file_dir/_thumbs/Pics/Artist/Clr---miljoe#270_mellem.jpg":
>   Permission denied (13)

However; there are no permission issues. It syncs other files, I can touch files, delete and all with no problem in the same directory.

I did try changing the locale to a bunch of different locales, I tried rsyncing with --iconv but still no bueno.

Unfortunately I am out of ideas. I can easily sync the files between two local directories.

Comment: Which version of nfs you use? V3 supports only ASCII names. For unicode support you have to mount with version4

Comment: Thanks for that! I changed to NFSv4, but now I still get "failed to stat" and then in the end "Invalid argument (22)"  - but still on non-ascii files :(

Comment: can you get a packet capture with tcpdump?

Answer (score 1):

The FS8600s are strictly UTF-8 (maybe UTF-16, but I think I recall UTF-8) compliant, so if you, in any way, try to put files with non-UTF8 compliant names on it (through CIFS or NFS or anything else), you will get the very non-descript 'Permission denied' error, you can put the files there, with a filename that is, apparently, the same, as long as it's UTF-8 encoded.

I'd recommend trying one of the solutions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets to make sure the filename is UTF-8 compliant and try to rsync the file again.